# "on average" in the Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

TLDR: I don't understand the bit in bold, i.e. where in the formula is the average q? Thanks.

The Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem states the following:

For any $A > 0$ there exists a $B = B(A)$ such that, for $Q= N^{\frac{1}{2}}(\log N)^{-B}$

$$\sum_{q \leq Q}\max_{\substack{a}\\{(a,q)=1}}|\psi(N;q,a) - \frac{N}{\varphi(q)}| \ll_{A} \frac{N}{(\log N)^{A}} $$

where $$\psi(N;q,a) = \sum_{\substack{n \leq N}\\ n \equiv a \mod q}\log n$$

if $n$ is a prime, and $0$ otherwise.

From my understanding, verbally this is addressing the error term of primes in arithmetic progression, for $\bf{q \leq Q}$ **on average**

Comment: The true statement is on wiki. It has an equivalent formulation in term of $\psi(N,\chi) = \sum_{p^k \le N} \chi(p^k) \log p$ and the result follows from the orthogonality of characters

Comment: @reuns I've looked at the wiki link and am still a bit confused.What is $y$ in the wiki formula? Also how does one arrive at the inequality for $Q$ i.e. $x^{\frac{1}{2}}\log^{-A}x \leq Q \leq x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ finally do you have a reference to the equivalent formulation you gave? Thanks.

Comment: @reuns I looked into it more. I see we can write $$\psi(x;q,a) = \frac{1}{\varphi(q)}\sum_{\chi \in X_{q}}\bar{\chi}(a)\psi(x, \chi)$$ and we can approximate $\psi(x, \chi)$ by an integral. So we are averaging over q. The difference in Bomberi Vinogadov is essentially the error term right?